# Compare contents of two folders by Hash to find duplicates

Tags: duplicate, checksum

I have two folders containing various files. These files don't have the same filename or the same creation Date. They may be identical though as far as the actual file is concerned.

I executed a powerShell Script to get a list of the filenames.

See this example, where neither filename nor creation date are identical, but the file itself actually is. The MD5 Checksum proves it.

[image: screenshot]

I want to keep only one version and delete the ones that are duplicates.

Edit: the concrete question is this: 
In the example I did the highlight myself, using a texteditor. What program would give me an output like that for a large list of files?

Comment: is there a question here?

Comment: The question is how can I do it for a large list of files. I have taken only a small list as an example. Obviously I can spot it if there are four, but if there are way more files, I can't think of a way to do it. I did a bit of research and found several solutions that work great for filenames and such, like Total Commander and winmerge.

Comment: Or try searching [SU] for “``awk``”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. A program called DoubleKiller does what I was looking for. http://www.bigbangenterprises.de/en/doublekiller/